# WSO2 ESB 4.5.0, authentication issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2esb 4.5.0 and I'm having an uncomfortable problem, my session is being closed constantly, sometimes I've to log in several times in one minute. Is there some way to avoid it?

Here is the trace in logs:

```
[2012-10-06 02:15:55,176]  INFO - RegistryEventingServiceComponent Successfully Initialized Eventing on Registry

[2012-10-06 02:15:56,063]  INFO - JMXServerManager JMX Service URL  : service:jmx:rmi://localhost:11111/jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi

[2012-10-06 02:15:56,070]  INFO - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent Server           :  WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus-4.5.0

[2012-10-06 02:15:56,072]  INFO - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent WSO2 Carbon started in 60 sec

[2012-10-06 02:15:56,651]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent Mgt Console URL  : https://localhost:9443/carbon/

[2012-10-06 02:16:27,059]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2012-10-06 02:16:27,058-0400]

[2012-10-06 02:16:37,230]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2012-10-06 02:16:37,230-0400]

[2012-10-06 02:16:58,958]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2012-10-06 02:16:58,958-0400]

[2012-10-06 02:17:10,045]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2012-10-06 02:17:10,045-0400]

[2012-10-06 02:17:18,099]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2012-10-06 02:17:18,099-0400]

[2012-10-06 02:17:24,248]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2012-10-06 02:17:24,248-0400]

[2012-10-06 02:17:32,390]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2012-10-06 02:17:32,390-0400]

[2012-10-06 02:17:41,048]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2012-10-06 02:17:41,048-0400]

[2012-10-06 02:17:46,394]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2012-10-06 02:17:46,394-0400]

[2012-10-06 02:17:54,714]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2012-10-06 02:17:54,714-0400]

[2012-10-06 02:18:09,476]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2012-10-06 02:18:09,476-0400]

[2012-10-06 02:18:17,606]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2012-10-06 02:18:17,606-0400]

[2012-10-06 02:18:21,561]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2012-10-06 02:18:21,561-0400]

[2012-10-06 02:18:31,615]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2012-10-06 02:18:31,615-0400]
```

Thanks in advance,
Ubalquis.

Answer (score 0):

Have you disabled cookies on your browser ? Please enable cookies if you have disabled.

Comment: No, cookies are enabled. I'm using another WSO2 products such as AS, GReg and IS and all of them are working fine, the problem is only with the ESB on Windows XP.